# ScrollView distrubing ListView inside of LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, scrollview

I have LinearLayout whcih contains Buttons and ListViews. After getting many buttons and I decide to put that LinearLayout into ScrollView but after putting ScrollView my ListViews are showing only one Item.

Following is the code before ScrollView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".WorkplaceObservationActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_reportType"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Report Type" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_reportType"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_defineJob"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Define Job" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_Jobs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_timeLocation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Time and Location" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_timeLocation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_setCurrentTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="Use current time and date" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_setCustomTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="Enter custom time" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_setCustomDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="Enter custom date" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Time and Date: "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_ReportDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Report Details" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_ReportDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_CaptureVideo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Capture Video" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_ReportDetailsItems"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Review"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Review" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_Review"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_Review_ReportType"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Report Type: "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_Review_DateTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date and Time: "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_Review_SupportingFiles"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Supporting Files: "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_ReviewItems"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone" >
        </ListView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Review_Send"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_Review_Save"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Save Draft" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_Review_Discard"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Discard" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

for Above Code I am getting Following Screen Shot
[image]

Following is the xml code after ScrollView

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".WorkplaceObservationActivity" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_reportType"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Report Type" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_reportType"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" >
        </ListView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_defineJob"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Define Job" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_Jobs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
            android:visibility="gone" >
        </ListView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_timeLocation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Time and Location" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_timeLocation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_setCurrentTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="Use current time and date" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_setCustomTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="Enter custom time" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_setCustomDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="Enter custom date" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Time and Date: "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_ReportDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Report Details" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_ReportDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_CaptureVideo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Capture Video" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lv_ReportDetailsItems"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Review"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Review" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_Review"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_Review_ReportType"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Report Type: "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_Review_DateTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date and Time: "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_Review_SupportingFiles"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Supporting Files: "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lv_ReviewItems"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone" >
            </ListView>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_Review_Send"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Send" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_Review_Save"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Save Draft" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_Review_Discard"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Discard" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and following is the sceen shot of above

[image]

I want to show complete list of items after scrollview.

Comment: i have completely the same problem, but want to show several lists.. and buttons in a big vertical scrollview (always vertical..) but facing the same problem :( any update?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a conflict between the `ScrollView` and the `ListView`. In general, you cannot put a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`. `ListView` already understands about scrolling and will scroll itself. `ListView` needs to know how much vertical space on the screen it should use, so that it can control the scrolling and display of its children. It is difficult to understand how the layout that you've posted should behave.

In any case, the only way to put a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView` is to tell the `ListView` exactly how much vertical space it should use. You cannot use `match_parent` or `wrap_content` for `layout_height`, you need to fix the vertical size. This helps the `ScrollView` to determine how much vertical space each of its children takes up, and then the `ScrollView` can do the right thing.

Try setting `android:layout_height="80dp"` on all of your `ListView`s to see how this behaves.

**EDIT: After looking at the layout again, I have another suggestion**

After looking at the layout again, I am assuming that you want to have only one of the `ListView`s visible at a given time (the others would all be **GONE**). In this case, you might try the following:

1. Remove the surrounding `ScrollView`
2. Set `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:layout_height="1px"` on all `ListView`s

This basically tells the layout manager that the `ListView` should be given all available space on the screen (ie: whatever is left over after the other `View`s are laid out). This will make the `ListView` expand to take up all available space on the screen, while keeping all the other `View`s on screen and the entire screen will not scroll, only the `ListView`. This may be a better way to give you what you want.

You might also consider using `ExpandableListView`, which seems to be what you are trying to recreate here.

Comment: Thanks for Help. I have to re-think about my UI design. in Which will try `ExpandableListView`.

Answer (score 2):

You can not have directly or indirectly a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`. That's because they will figth to manage touch events. You have to re-think about your UI design

Comment: probably addHeaderView and addFooteraView of ListView is all you need

Answer (score 1):

Do one thing try giving hard coded height to your listview for example android:layou_height="100dp" and it will work but this is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the android:layout_width="wrap_content" to android:layout_width="match_parent" o listview.

Comment: `layout_width` has absolutely nothing to do with this problem. The problem here is `layout_height`.